# how to access cache from other views

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, caching, asihttprequest

I have set up a sharedCache using ASIHttprequest and it is created from the xml I parse in my subview. I was woundering if I can then access that sharedCache from my mainview to do a few things things that will speed my tables up?

any idea, suggestions, thoughts of examples would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's already a `sharedCache` provided by `ASIDownloadCache`. It's visible anywhere in your application (assuming you `#import "ASIDownloadCache.h"`), so you should be able to call `[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]` and use it.

*EDIT:* To use several caches is not too tricky. Create a separate class which is included by both your main view and your subview. In there, define a method to return one or more `ASIDownloadCache` objects, and provide an implementation, similar to this:

---

DownloadCaches.h

```
#import "ASIDownloadCache.h"

@interface DownloadCaches : NSObject

    + (ASIDownloadCache *)imageCache;

@end
```

---

DownloadCaches.m

```
#import "DownloadCaches.h"

@implementation DownloadCaches
    static ASIDownloadCache *imageCache = nil;

    + (ASIDownloadCache *)imageCache
    {
        if(imageCache == nil)
        {
            imageCache = [[ASIDownloadCache alloc] init];
            // set imageCache-specific options here
        }

        return imageCache;
    }

@end
```

You only ever need to call `[DownloadCaches imageCache]` and it will be initialised if not already, and then returned to you.

Comment: okay cool... I thought this was the case but I'm slightly confused by the way I have managed to set up my cache.. I have no idea where I am saving it.. or how I can create multiple caches :P currently I only have one but as I develop my app further i would like to have several.